# Modify error messages for validation with an option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have already modified quite a few option error messages as shown below

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        name: "Name"
        email: "E-mail address"
        password: "Password"
        password_confirmation: "Password confirmation"
    errors:
      messages:
        blank: "%{attribute} is required"
        taken: "%{attribute} is already taken"
        invalid: "%{attribute} is not valid"
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            password:
              confirmation: "%{attribute} doesn't match confirmation"
```

Yet, I don't know how I can modify the error message for the **length** when it's not **within** a **specified range**. I know it's possible to do so (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models) but I don't know how?

Thanks,

Comment: In the very same guide you linked, there is a table ('4.5.2 Error Message Interpolation') where you can see in the message column which key will be used to translate the error message. For example, if you `validates :some_attr, length: { in: 1..5 }` then you should be able to redefine `[...].errors.messages.too_short: "%{count} letters is too much"` and the `too_long` key/value pair too

Comment: Try something with "maximum/minimum". When you declare length, you can set size with those two arguments. I will test here. Come on @MrYoshiji.. let me answer one at once! hahaha lol - As MrYoshiji commented, you can validate that in your model and make it easier to add custom error messages.

Comment: How about put the error message in a model validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found these tags in my app. One of those should work for you!

```
equal_to: must be equal to %{count}
greater_than: must be greater than %{count}
greater_than_or_equal_to: must be greater or equal to %{count}
less_than: must be less than %{count}
less_than_or_equal_to: must be less or equal than %{count}
too_long:
  one: 'is to short (max than: 1 character)'
  other: 'is to long (max than: %{count} characteres)'
too_short:
  one: 'is to short (min: 1 character)'
  other: 'is to short (min: %{count} characteres)'
wrong_length:
  one: doesn't have the right length (1 character)
  other: doesn't have the right length (%{count} characteres)
other_than: must be different than %{count}
```